# Mathjax support in github using a Chrome browser plugin?

Tags: r, github, mathjax

I'd like Mathjax to work on all my github pages (e.g., Markdown displayed on github, issue trackers). I have a lot of files generated from R Markdown that also have equations.

While I'd love github to provide optional support for Mathjax, I thought a more realistic aim would be to have some browser plugin that detects that I'm on a github page and automatically runs the mathjax script.

- Are there any browser plugins for the Chrome browser that automatically run a MathJaX script on specified URLs (e.g., `http*github*`)?

#### Initial thoughts

There's quite a [long discussion on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/22141/how-do-i-see-latex-math-on-any-web-page-and-in-email). However, the discussion includes discussion of a range of technologies (not just MathJax) and many of the solutions are specific to the Firefox browser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a GreaseMonkey script that should do what you want: [Run MathJax in Github](http://www.math.union.edu/locate/Cervone/transfer/mathjax/mathjax-in-github.user.js).  It should work in all the major browser (though some need plugins to run GreaseMonkey scripts; see the installation instructions for [this question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4208/a-prototype-for-incremental-preview-updates) for details).

This script only loads MathJax on pages that contain TeX or MathML markup (it does a very simple test for that, which certainly could be made more sophisticated).  Note that the default delimiters are `\(...\)` for in-line math and `\[...\]` or `$$...$$` for displayed math.  In particular, single-dollars aren't enable as math delimiters (since they occur too frequently in ordinary non-math text).  If you wanted to enable single-dollar delimiters, you would need to edit the script to add a MathJax configuration script prior to loading MathJax.js itself.

The script is set to trigger on `http://github.com/*` and `https://github.com/*`.  Not all the GreaseMonkey implementations provide for pattern matching in the host part of the URL, but if yours does, you can make it more sophisticated so that it will get subdomains of github as well.

Hope that does what you need.

**Edit**: The script now enables `$...$` for in-line math, as requested by the asker.

Comment: Thanks. That sounds like exactly what I was after. Of course, it just so happens that most of my current documents use single dollar delimiters. I'm personally happy to deal with the risk that it might incorrectly render the occasional page with a single dollar. I also found that some double dollar delimiters are not being rendered. I had a look at the script, but I wasn't quite sure how to update it to support single dollar delimiters.

Comment: @JeromyAnglim, I have modified the script to include single-dollars for in-line math.  Remove the current version of the extension and use the link above again to get the updated version.

Comment: Wow. Awesome. That works really well. I just have to remember not to leave blank lines after multiline code and the closing `$$`. But that sounds like a good idea anyway.

Comment: That is what is required by TeX anyway, so it is a good habit to be in.  Is that the problem you were having with the delimiters that you mentioned above?  If not, can you say more about that, or point me to a page that shows the problem?

Comment: Yes. That was the source of the problem with the double delimiters above. It all works well now. (and yes I should get into good habits with double dollars; I guess whatever script Rstudio inserts is a little bit more tolerant)

Comment: I think one other thing that confused me is that the script does not always work with the standard slide-to-open interface on github. For example, if you are browsing a repository and click on an md file, github has this sliding effect which seems to prevent the script from working. If you refresh the page, the script works.

Comment: Right, MathJax only typesets what is part of the page initially.  If the content is altered dynamically, as it is with the "slide out" effect, then you would need to call MathJax again to typeset the new material.  It probably would be possible to do that automatically, but it would take work to analyze the code used by GitHub so that you can hook into the right place, and I don't have the time to do that.  Alternatively, you could add a floating button that would ask MathJax to typeset again so you could manually do it (rather than reload the page).

Comment: Chrome won't allow this script, it says it only allows scripts to install from the chrome store. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: I thought this extension would solve it - https://github.com/andrusha/mathml-chrome - but it doesn't work on github markdown view. This one - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tex-the-world-for-chromiu/mbfninnbhfepghkkcgdnmfmhhbjmhggn - does the job, but you need [; ;] instead of $ $.

Comment: seems to not work anymore because github uses CSP now