# LaTeX math in github wikis

Tags: github, latex, wiki

Is it possible to include LaTeX-style math in any way with github repo wikis? Googling implies github no longer allows things like MathJax, but most references are years old. What (if any) alternatives are there to including LaTeX-formatted math in github wikis?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11256433

Comment: I was hoping there would be an update in the past two years. Using URL encoding is absurd for anything reasonably complex.

Comment: What about now? It's January 2017 ... and I'm still not sure what to use?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show math equations in general github's markdown(not github's blog)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11256433/how-to-show-math-equations-in-general-githubs-markdownnot-githubs-blog)

Answer (score 24):

You can use `chart.apis.google.com` to render LaTeX formulas as PNG.
It work nicely with Githhub's markdown:

**Example (Markdown):**

```
The ratio of the momentum to the velocity is
the relativistic mass, m.

![f1]

And the relativistic mass and the relativistic
kinetic energy are related by the formula:

![f2]

Einstein wanted to omit the unnatural second term
on the right-hand side, whose only purpose is
to make the energy at rest zero, and to declare
that the particle has a total energy, which obeys:
![f3] which is a sum of the rest energy ![f4]
and the kinetic energy.

[f1]: http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=m=\frac{m_0}{\sqrt{1-{\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}}
[f2]: http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=E_k=mc^2-m_0c^2
[f3]: http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=E=mc^2
[f4]: http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=m_0c^2
```

**https**

Some installations of Github Enterprise reject `http` and work only if you use `https`

**Rendered:**
[image]

Comment: It looks like I need an extra \\ for the latex commands like \frac to render correctly using your method for example ```[f1]: http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=m=\\frac{m_0}{\\sqrt{1-{\\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}}```

Comment: I would say you just write single backslashes, it works in stackoverflow rendering and I tested it by copy-pasting to chrome addressbar.

Comment: It does the job, it looks decent when rendered, but the point of Markdown was to have something legible even when not rendered and having links make it illegible. It's not your fault, it's just limitation of GitHub :-(

Answer (score 12):

For simple formulas (such as exponents etc) you may one just to use the available render languages. For example, using Textile, you can do:

```
_E = mc ^2^_
```

Thiw will be rendered as:

> [image]
>
> `_` is used for italic style and `^` for superscript.

You can do the same thing in Markdown adding some HTML:

```
*E = mc<sup>2</sup>*
```

You can see it in action in this very place:

> *E = mc<sup>2</sup>*

If you're looking for support for complex math formulas, then you have no better option than using a third-party service generating images for you. [mathUrl](http://mathurl.com/) looks interesting.

As input we give it `E = mc ^ 2` and it generates the following link:

> [image]
>
> http://mathurl.com/render.cgi?E%20%3D%20mc%20%5E%202%5Cnocache

Answer (score 2):

There is good solution for your problem - use [TeXify](https://github.com/apps/texify) github plugin - more details about this plugin and explanation why this is good approach you can find in that [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53981118/860099).

Answer (score 2):

GitLab Wiki and markdown supports formulas. I moved multiple repos for this reason.

Answer (score 1):

Now GitHub [officially supports showing Mathjax](https://github.blog/2022-05-19-math-support-in-markdown/) in the wiki!

In Markdown, just use `$` as the deliminator of inline formulas, and `$$` as the deliminator of display formulas.

Answer (score 0):

To add math equations to a GitHub wiki, I used [mathURL](http://mathurl.com/) as suggested by [Ionică](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1420197/ionic%C4%83-biz%C4%83u). It will render your LaTeX equations. Append `.png` to the generated url and use that url as an image (either block or inline) in your markdown.

Comment: While it is an option it is a pretty limited one. It doesn't support loading of LaTeX packages hence you have to stick to the very basics.