# how to support math formula in github.io markdown?

Tags: markdown, github-pages, mathjax

https://github.com/zhaochenyou/TestMathJax

This is a test project for mathjax. I init /docs/README.md with:

```
<script type="text/javascript" async
  src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML">
</script>

formula1:
$$n==x$$

formula2: $$n!=x$$

formula3:
\(m==y\)

formula4: \[m!=y\]

formula5:
\\(k==z\\)

formula6: \\[k!=z\\]
```

but it seems not working at `https://zhaochenyou.github.io/TestMathJax/`

please help me ?

Comment: What you are trying to do can't be done in markdown. Use a html page instead

Comment: html is too complicated for document.... I want simple writing and math formula in markdown...

Comment: Yeah but you can't use scripts in markdown :P

Comment: oh, no... sad sad

Comment: It works as expected for me, ie. 1,2,5,6 work fine. You might want to check the kramdown documentation for math blocks.

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger, I found the bug, because I'm new to html/css and latex math formula, I write formula with bugs, the bug is in formula, not github pages.

Comment: Good to hear you could figure it out.

Comment: GitHub supports [Latex/MathJax since May 2022](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72310304/6309).