# Any solutions for publishing docx/latex or latex on github.io/gitbook?

Tags: github, markdown, github-pages

I have write some document, it include lots of formulas, pictures. I want to publish them on github.io, for reading online.

I have tried markdown, but it doesn't support math formula. Raw html is too complicated for document writing. Translate docx/latex to png/jpeg cost too much storage on github.

Are there any good solutions for document publishing on github.io or gitbook ?

Comment: Contrary to what your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43713030/how-to-support-math-formula-in-github-io-markdown) suggests, MathJax works just fine on GitHub pages.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the website https://stackedit.io/

If you experiment with the export functions, you may be able to obtain raw HTML that resembles the formatting and style of Github, although it may not be exactly what you're seeking.