# How to show math expressions in Bitbucket and github markdown?

Tags: github, latex, bitbucket, markdown, mathjax

How can I show formatted math expressions in Bitbucket or github markdown?

[This feature is highly requested](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/11192/add-latex-support-in-markdown-documents-bb) and have been under development for years now.  There does not seem to be a decent solution for it yet.

Formatted math is supported in [reStructuredText](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#math) and I can use it as a last resort.  But as markdown gains popularity I would rather stick to it than use yet another markup language.

Comment: GitHub supports [Latex/MathJax since May 2022](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72310304/6309).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Bitbucket](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/markdown-syntax-guide-776639995.html)'s (and [GitHub's](https://github.com/STAT545-UBC/Discussion/issues/102)) Markdown does not currently support formatted math expressions. A good workaround I discovered that works with both is to use **[codecogs](https://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php)** to convert my LaTeX math expression into a hosted image and use its URL to embed it in my Markdown document.

## Example:

Go to **[codecogs](https://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php)** and enter your LaTeX equation in the text box.

```latex
\zeta(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^s}
```

Right click the **Click here to Download Image (GIF)** link shown under the text box and copy the link's address.  Then, embed the URL in your markdown document as an image:

```
![my equation](https://latex.codecogs.com/gif.download?%5Czeta%28s%29%20%3D%20%5Csum_%7Bn%3D1%7D%5E%5Cinfty%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bn%5Es%7D)
```

The image should show in your formatted Markdown document like:

[image: my equation]

This method also works with GitHub and any Markdown processor that supports externally hosted images.

Also, [mathURL](http://mathurl.com/) offers a similar service and a nice interface but does not support https (can't use with GitHub).

Comment: What options do you choose, for font family, size etc?

Comment: The problem with images is that they don't look good when your tool/browser is set to dark mode. Apart from that, good idea!

Answer (score 0):

At least in the past few years, there has been little progress in this area. You can only get unclear formulas through pictures.

But [GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/markdown.html#math) supports mathematical formulas, you need to note that gitlab uses its **own flavored** formula delimiters instead of the most general `dollars`.

- inline: $...$
- display: $$...$$

Although you can solve this problem with the following vscode extension, it is still not elegant enough.

https://github.com/yzhang-gh/vscode-markdown

https://github.com/goessner/mdmath