# How to use MathJax in an Rmarkdown github_document?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I would like to include some math symbols in my GitHub README file generated by Rmarkdown. However, enclosing the symbols in `$` does not render them as symbols: it just puts parentheses around them. Based on [this document](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/github_document_format.html), I thought perhaps I could use MathJax, but my efforts to get this to work have been unsuccessful so far. Any help would be appreciated!

**Attempt 1:**

```
---
output:
  github_document
---
Here are some math symbols: $/alpha$ $A$ $1$
```

**Attempt 2:**

```
---
output:
  github_document:
    pandoc_args: "--mathjax"
---
Here are some math symbols: $/alpha$ $A$ $1$
```

**Attempt 3:**

```
---
output:
  github_document:
    pandoc_args: [
      "--mathjax", "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"
    ]
---
Here are some math symbols: $/alpha$ $A$ $1$
```

**Attempt 4:**

```
---
output:
  github_document:
    md_extensions: -tex_math_single_backslash+tex_math_dollars
---
Here are some math symbols: $/alpha$ $A$ $1$
```

So far, all of these attempts produced this:

[image]

Comment: I previously used output: rmarkdown::github_document alone. This rendered dollar-bracketed text in mathtype. This functionality was lost when I updated to R 3.6. I did not manage to rescue it with this configuration. However, installing R 3.5.3 alongside, I was able to produce an output with the correct mathtype formatting, as before. I did not manage to narrow down which changes produced this effect. I'd be interested to know what changed, and if the functionality can be recovered in R 3.6.3.

Answer (score 1):

That´s a difficult question and lot of people asked them before, see e.g. 
https://github.com/github/markup/issues/897

I found a simple solution for some small formulas, e.g. for alpha:

Just use `&alpha`
You can also sub- or superscript with  <sub>...</sub>  or  <sup>...</sup> 
(see more here: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp)

Solution found here:
[How to show math equations in general github's markdown(not github's blog)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11256433/how-to-show-math-equations-in-general-githubs-markdownnot-githubs-blog)