# How to show the + symbol in an equation that is generated by https://render.githubusercontent.com for github-pages?

Tags: github-pages, github-flavored-markdown

I can't seem to get the "+" symbol to appear:

```
<img src="https://render.githubusercontent.com/render/math?math={\color{black} \large \sigma = f(\mu) = a\mu^2 + b\mu + c} ">   Eqn(2)
```

It is giving me this [wrong result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPBZq.png). The appearance I desire is [this correct appearance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjvIP.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting a comment by @Jishan in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67711933/9947200)

> Anyone using this method, because + is an escape character in URI, use %2B to render +.